# Burnt offering of a gentile

Tags: gentiles, korban

According to this [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13671/did-paroh-give-offerings), the pharoah of Egypt in the time of Moses gave a burnt offering to Moses.

This inspired me to do research (read: google) about gentiles bringing in burnt offerings.

From this [website:](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/jewfaq/qorbanot.htm)

> "An olah could be brought from cattle, sheep, goats, or even doves.  Gentiles were allowed to bring an olah in our Temple, unlike the rest of the kinds of qorbanot, which were reserved for Jews alone within the Temple itself; it should be remembered, however, that Gentiles are permitted to build their own place for qorbanot, and offer them to God themselves, and are promised reward for this meritorious behavior. "

So, gentiles are allowed to give burnt offering in the temple. 
It also says gentiles are allowed to build their own place to give this burnt offering.

What are the specifications of such an alter built by gentiles, and after building, what is the process of such an offering done by a gentile?

Answer (score 11):

The Korban does need to be brought on an altar (Rambam Maaseh Korbanot 19:1). This altar though does not have the requirements of horns, a ramp, a base, and square corners which regular altars (including a Bamah Gedolah, though that isn't the case here (Megilla 9b)) have (Zevachim 108b). I don't see any other listed exclusions, so presumably other requirements of the altar apply, such as a minimum size of 1x1x3 Amot (Rambam Beit HaBerchira 2:17). The materials for the altar (including the wood for the fire) may not have been used constructively for humans beforehand (Zevachim 116b).

They can offer any kosher mammal or bird even if it has a blemish (ibid. 115b) unless it is missing an entire limb (ibid. 116a).

The gentile may slaughter his own Korban even though generally gentiles cannot perform a valid Shechita.

I see no indication or reason why the procedure of catching and sprinkling the blood should be any different.

Jews may instruct the gentiles regarding the proper methodology but cannot assist in any way. This can be done nowadays even outside of Israel. (Rambam Maaseh Korbanot 19:16)

Comment: Incidentally, this is the _correct_ answer to "What would you go do if you found out you weren't Jewish?"

Comment: Is there anybody who does this nowadays? Perhaps some of the Noahide communities do it?

Comment: @Daniel I've never heard of it. It's not obligatory.

Comment: Is there a requirement of leaving the fire lit? What can be used to light the fire? What is done in regards to cleaning the alter?

Comment: @Nail No. Flint? Nothing. The fire and cleaning of the Mizbeach in the Temple are rules about the Temple not about offering a Korban.

Comment: "I see no indication or reason why the procedure of catching and sprinkling the blood should be any different." See the last mishnah and gemara in Zevachim, starting here: https://www.sefaria.org/Zevachim.119b.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en