# Bringing a korban *before* conversion

Tags: gentiles, korban

Bringing a korban these days is halachicly problematic for various reasons.   (tumah, Kohen status, location, etc.).  For these reasons, a convert is currently exempt from bringing a korban.

However, it seems to me that these issues might go away if the would-be convert brought the korban *before* he converted, as long as it doesn't somehow fall under "idol worship" (see also [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45515/burnt-offering-of-a-gentile/45518)).

There is a valid question as to the utility of such an offering.  After all, there is no obligation for a non-jew to do so.   On the other hand, we've seen historic instances of non-jews bringing offerings that are looked on with favor (e.g. Hevel), so one could argue that there is a net positive here.   At the very least, it could provide practical experience (to onlookers) for when offerings are eventually reinstated.

To summarize, I am asking if there are any sources that discuss non-Jews bringing offerings in modern times and if this is considered a positive or objectionable idea.

Comment: "At the very least, it could provide practical experience (to onlookers) for when offerings are eventually reinstated."  I don't think you need to jump through hoops to do that.  You can just have in mind that it's not a korban (and make sure you're not violating any laws) and you're fine.  Especially if you're doing a fake shelamim+variants/asham/non-Kohen mincha/standard non-bird chatas, you're not even wasting the meat, you can eat it.  The parts that get burned are not kosher anyway.

Comment: Yes gentiles can bring offerings nowadays https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45518/759

Comment: That's a good related question.  I will add a link