# Non-Jewish altars and sacrifices through the history

Tags: gentiles, korban

Before Avraham, we see that many Non-[officially]-Jews [Kain, Abel,Noah, Shem] built stages/altars for offerings to G-d.

From then, through the periods of the Temples and nowadays, when were the Non-Jews allowed to build stages/altars (במות/מזבחות) to offer their sacrifices to [one, our] G-d? And are they allowed to do that today?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45515/759

Comment: @DoubleAA A wonderful answer. You can mark this question as a true duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Non-Jews may sacrifice to G-d on any private altar they build, anywhere in the world.

[Rambam Hilchot Ma'aseh HaKorbanot 19:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sacrificial_Procedure.19.16?lang=bi):

> וְהַנָּכְרִים מֻתָּרִין לְהַקְרִיב עוֹלוֹת לַשֵּׁם בְּכָל מָקוֹם. וְהוּא שֶׁיַּקְרִיבוּ בְּבָמָה שֶׁיִּבְנוּ.‏
>
> Non-Jews may offer burnt offerings to G-d in any place, offering them on an altar which they have built.

Comment: Great, Thanks, any examples in the last millennia?

Comment: I haven't heard of any...

Comment: I saw a video of one on Har Zion (the southern part of the Old City).