# Why would a non-Jew offer a sacrifice?

Tags: gentiles, korban, noachide-laws

It seems that gentiles are [allowed to offer burnt sacrifices, and may do so anywhere in the world](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/104855/13933). They do not need the Temple. A Jew may even [instruct](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45518/13933) a gentile on how to do this.

What is the purpose of a gentile offering a korban? That is, what does it actually *do* for them? Offering sacrifices doesn't seem to be commanded by the seven Noachide laws in the same way that Jews are ordered to bring sacrifices. Does a gentile's korban grant specific blessings or atone for specific sins, or is it purely something they can do if they feel like it?

Comment: What would Noah and Job say? It's obvious they believed there was some benefit.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that they are not commanded to bring sacrifices. Your question is mentioned by Rambam in [Mishnah Torah, Hilchot Melachim, chapter 10, halacha 10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.10.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which says:

> בֶּן נֹחַ שֶׁרָצָה לַעֲשׂוֹת מִצְוָה מִשְּׁאָר מִצְוֹת הַתּוֹרָה כְּדֵי לְקַבֵּל שָׂכָר. אֵין מוֹנְעִין אוֹתוֹ לַעֲשׂוֹתָהּ כְּהִלְכָתָהּ. וְאִם הֵבִיא עוֹלָה מְקַבְּלִין מִמֶּנּוּ.

As Rambam presents it, the non-Jew is bringing the offering for whatever perceived reward or merit they think G-d may credit them with because it is one of the commandments in the Torah.