# Chatat or Asham for Non-Jews?

Tags: gentiles, korban, repentance-teshuvah

Related to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45798/teshuva-and-non-jews) and [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45515/burnt-offering-of-a-gentile).

[Non-Jews can make sacrifices anywhere in the world](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104854/non-jewish-altars-and-sacrifices-through-the-history/104855#104855), [regardless if there's a Mikdash standing or not](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/jewfaq/qorbanot.htm). Technically, [Jews need to bring a Korban Chatat or an Asham as part of the Teshuvah process](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), but as there is no Mikdash, we only keep the other parts of Teshuvah. Would a Non-Jew who is doing Teshuvah be required to sacrifice a Chatat?

Comment: "Jews need to bring a Korban Chatat as part of the Teshuvah process" Source? In the entire Laws of Teshuva of the Rambam, he mentions the word Korban in only one law where he notes that Korbanot don't atone without Teshuva. Seems you have it backwards and Teshuva is part of the Korban process.

Comment: @DoubleAA why? Rambam says that now that there isn't a Mikdash, all that's left is the Teshuvah process. And when there is a Mikdash, what does that mean? That there are also Korbanot to be given.

Comment: I'm not denying that certain sins generate an obligation to bring certain Korbanot. That's not Teshuva though.

Comment: @DoubleAA how would you define it? Atonement? Purification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Non-Jews may only offer a burnt offering to G-d.

[Rambam Hilchot Ma'aseh HaKorbanot 3:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sacrificial_Procedure.3.2):

> וְאֶחָד אֲנָשִׁים וְאֶחָד נָשִׁים אוֹ עֲבָדִים מְבִיאִין כָּל הַקָּרְבָּנוֹת. אֲבָל הָעַכּוּ''ם אֵין מְקַבְּלִין מֵהֶן אֶלָּא עוֹלוֹת בִּלְבַד שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ויקרא כב כה) "וּמִיַּד בֶּן נֵכָר לֹא תַקְרִיבוּ אֶת לֶחֶם אֱלֹהֵיכֶם". אֲפִלּוּ עוֹלַת הָעוֹף מְקַבְּלִין מִן הַנָּכְרִי אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא עוֹבֵד עֲבוֹדָה זָרָה. אֲבָל אֵין מְקַבְּלִין מֵהֶן שְׁלָמִים וְלֹא מְנָחוֹת וְלֹא חַטָּאוֹת וַאֲשָׁמוֹת. וְכֵן עוֹלוֹת שֶׁאֵינָן בָּאוֹת בְּנֵדֶר וּנְדָבָה אֵין מְקַבְּלִין אוֹתָן מִן הַנָּכְרִי כְּגוֹן עוֹלַת יוֹלֶדֶת וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהּ מֵעוֹלוֹת שֶׁאֵינָן בָּאוֹת מִשּׁוּם נֵדֶר וְלֹא מִשּׁוּם נְדָבָה:‏
>
> [Jewish] males, females and slaves can bring any of the offerings. But from a non-Jew we only accept burnt offerings...

Comment: Is this true even when the non-Jew is sacrificing in his own altar? That is, the phrasing of the Rambam sounds as though this din is in the case of a non-Jew wanting to sacrifice specifically in the Mikdash.

Comment: @Harel13 On his own altar, Rambam only says he can bring burnt offerings https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/104855/759